# data members to consider while overriding hashcode and equals

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I know (contract) we need to override hashcode when equals is overridden.
Why should I consider same fields used for equals comparison to compute hashcode?
Is it to improve performance, by avoiding too many objects mapping to same bucket, as in below case?
i.e. all objects created on same "date" would map to same bucket and linear comparison will take time in checking object exists using equals() method?

If my above statement is true, what other potential issues will come with below code other than performance issue. Is that the only reason we should use same fields / members used in equals to compute hashcode? Please share. Thanks.

```
class MyClass {
  int date;
  int pay;
  int id;

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    //null and same class instance check
    MyClass obj = (MyClass) o;
    return (date == obj.date && pay == obj.pay && id == obj.id);
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    return (31 * hash + date);
  }
}
```

//please pardon syntax errors, I typed without using ide.

***my intention is to use all fields in equals, and know why same number of elements should be used in hashcode, and what happens if only few elements are used

**Clarification:** 
With only using "date" to compute hashcode,pointer checks right bucket address (do you agree?) furthermore, I get list of items in that bucket, collection will iterate over to check if particular obj exists using equals. And my definition of equals is "all fields must be same". With this, I believe my code works fine, and I only find performance issue. Please point out where I am wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in Effective Java, by Joshua Bloch, 2nd edtn, page 49 "Do not be tempted to exclude significant parts of an object from the hash code computation to improve performance" . The poor quality may degrade hash tables' performance.

So my guess was right, multiple hashes will map to same bucket.

Additional information: 
http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2002/10/equalhash.html

> Since the class members/variables num and data do participate in the
>   equals method comparison, they should also be involved in the
>   calculation of the hash code. **Though, this is not mandatory.** You can
>   use subset of the variables that participate in the equals method
>   comparison to improve performance of the hashCode method. Performance
>   of the hashCode method indeed is very important.

Comment: You also have to consider the requirement (mentioned elsewhere in the same book, IIRC) that `hashcode()` is **consistent with equals**.  Basically, this means that if `obj1.equals(obj2)`, then `obj1` and `obj2` *must* have the same hash value.  The reverse is not true; if `!obj1.equals(obj2)` and they *do* have the same hash value, it's not actually wrong, but hash-based collections will perform badly.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, yes I am aware of that, my point was to understand if code fails when : if 'n' members are used in equals() comparison and I use 'less than n' member for hashcode, will my code break or something. But it doesn't break, but reduces performance by increasing chances of mapping multiple objects to same bucket. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For your example, I suggest you use just `id` for equality and that annotate that they're overrides. Also, I like to override `toString()`

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o instanceof MyClass) {
    return (id == ((MyClass) o).id);
  }
  return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
  return String.format("MyClass (id=%d, date=%d, pay=%d)", id, date, pay);
}
```

That way you can update the `date` and/or the `pay` without having to recreate the hash structure. Also, that's what appears to be unique about instances.

Comment: my intention is to use all fields in equals, and know why same number of elements should be used in hashcode, and what happens if only few elements are used/ thanks.

Comment: @DavidPrun Yes, I read your code. If you use all of the elements and your instance isn't immutable then changing a field will not work as your expect in a `HashSet` or `HashMap` because your instances will have changed their equality and hashCode value will not match the bucket the element is assigned to.

Comment: Elliott Frish, with only using "date" to compute hashcode,pointer checks right bucket address (do you agree?) furthermore, I get list of items in that bucket, collection will iterate over to check if particular obj exists using equals. And my definition of equals is "all fields must be same". With this, I believe my code in question works fine, and I only find performance issue. Please point out where I am wrong. Thank you.